# Best way to store non-essential data in web development?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a form to register books, and one of the fields is book's genre. The user will be able to choose the genre with a select, but I have no idea what to use to 'fill' this select: a XML file, JSON. I pretend to avoid a column or table in database.

Comment: What is your question actually? When you save that form, what do you expect to happen? And what happens now with your code?

Comment: a database table is the best way to store this data. Why do you want to avoid this?

Comment: I haven't write any code yet, is a question to have an idea. I want to avoid a extra table because I don't want to make an extra relationship. I think this: 

If I have the genres and subgenres table and a books table I will have to make a relationship... a little bit confusing. I think..

Comment: Avoiding a table with genres means missing relationships with your books and unable to index books according to genre if you ever plan to create a search function with a filter. Second, using a table with genres means you can create factories and seeders, test cases, etc. There is absolutely no reason to leave this table out. What if you want to create a hierarchy of genres? Every other storage method means duplicated data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to use JSON. In future it will be useful, if you want it to be dynamic. You can create REST API or store it in database as well

Comment: Do you mean I can store JSON in databse? I didn't understan very well

Comment: You can create json file genre.json and then expose an API which will read the json file and return response. In frontend you can consume it using javascript and fill the dropdown.

Comment: In future if you want to change storage mechanisam, example move this json to DB table and query it and response.

Comment: In other words, if the OP just took the time to do it right ones, he never would be in this situation of migrating json files to database tables.